Numerical evaluation of Fourier integral
I have the following well-known two-dimensional Fourier integral
$$
F(u,v) = \int_0^{\infty} dx \int_0^{\infty} dy f(x,y) \cos(2\pi x u) \cos(2\pi y v),
$$
which have to be evaluated numerically (i.e. it is assumed that $f(x,y)$ can be evaluated at any point) on the two-dimensional uniform grid:
$$
u_j = \Delta \cdot j\quad j=0,1,...,N, \\
v_k = \Delta \cdot k\quad k=0,1,...,M.
$$
There are a lot of techniques to evaluate Fourier integral:
$$
F(u) = \int_0^{\infty} f(x) \cos(2\pi x u) dx,
$$
for any $u$. See, for instance, T. Ooura, 2005 (https://doi.org/10.2977/prims/1145474603).
However, I would like to reduce redundant $f(x, y)$ evaluations, since I am calculating $N\cdot M$ integrals at once.
Assuming that $N$ and $M$ are large enough, one of naive obvious approaches would be to employ Discrete Fourier Transform, the initial integral has to be rewritten as the following:
$$
F(\Delta \cdot j, \Delta \cdot k) = \int_0^{1/2\Delta} dx \int_0^{1/2\Delta} dy \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} f(x + \frac{n}{2\Delta},y + \frac{m}{2\Delta}) \right) \cos(2\pi x \Delta j) \cos(2\pi y \Delta k),
$$
and then $x$ and $y$ are considered on the discrete uniform grid $0,1/N,...,1/2\Delta$. However, evaluating
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} f(x + \frac{n}{2\Delta},y + \frac{m}{2\Delta})
$$
series at every point is a new complex problem.
What could be an efficient and elegant way to solve initial numerical problem?
